# AWS: Microsoft Remote Server unable to connect

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a running instance on AWS and seem to be having an issue. :(

I'm connecting via Microsoft Remote Desktop (on a mac) to a windows server.

The username, passwords, etc., are correct. I just keep recieving this error:

Unable to connect to remote PC. Please verify Remote Desktop is enabled, the remote PC is turned on and available on the network, and then try again.

On Stack Exchange they are saying it's because of the inbound rules... to check whether I am on port 3389.. but I AM!

Does anyone know what else could be causing this issue? Much appreciated!

Comment: AWS changes the Windows localhost\Administrator password *automatically*. I forget how often, but I know it does. I would login and make sure you're using the current password. Also, I'd check Security Groups in AWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-rdp.html

Comment: Can you provide more details, history, etc. Post your security group (inbound), have you been able to connect previously, etc. The error message appears to indicate that you either have the port blocked or you do not have RDP running on the server.

Comment: Did you put your server in a public or private subnet? Does it have a public IP address assigned? Have you created the inbound rule in your security group?

Comment: @JohnHanley Have not been able to connect previously.

Answer (score 0):

Can check following possibilities

- **EC2 Instence**
    -Does it have a public IP address
- **The Security Group** 
    Does the security group have inbound allow rules for HTTPS and/or SSH 
    (port 3389/ port 22). 
    Does the HTTP and/or SSH all for traffic from all sources (0.0.0.0/0).
- **The Subnet**
    Does the subnets route table have a route to the Internet Gateway.
    Does the Network Access Control List protecting the subnet have inbound 
    allow rules for HTTPS and/or SSH.
    Does the Network Access Control List protecting the subnet have outbound 
    allow rules set for all traffic.
- **Internet Gateway**
     Is there an internet gateway attached to the VPC in which the EC2 
     instance has been provisioned.